# Php returns NULL for global variable

Tags: php, oop, global-variables

So I have the following code:

```
public function pcieh_shortcodes_init() {
    $data = $this->data;
    var_dump($data); //Return an array which is Expected       

    function pcieh_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null) {
         global $data;
         var_dump($data); //Return NULL
     }

    add_shortcode('pcieh', 'pcieh_shortcode');
}
```

When I call `pcieh_shortcodes_int` I expect the $data inside `pcieh_shortcode` to have the same value as outside $data since it's global but it returns NULL. Why is that and how can I fix it?

Comment: Clarify, please -- you expect the $data variable in the "pcieh_shortcode" function to have the value of the $data variable in this same function that was defined earlier, or as a yet-unseen $data variable that was defined external to the "pcieh_shortcodes_init" function? If it's the first, you don't need the "global" keyword. If it's the later, your first definition of $data in the line $data = $this->$data is probably masking what you expect to see.

Comment: $data is originally a private property of the class that contains pcieh_shortcodes_init method. I want $data in the pcieh_shortcode to have the same value as that class property but I want to do some calculations on it inside pcied_shortcodes_init before using it in pcieh_shortcode function

Comment: Then it's not a global variable. Just remove the "global" part. But I still don't fully understand what you mean. Your code shows a nested function ("pcieh_shortcode") that you define then just call. Why do you even need that? If you've reduced the code to make your question more clear, maybe we need more of your code and a description of what you want the result to be.

Comment: When I remove the global it shows undefined variable error. I modified the code to make question more clear. In original version I user another function to call pcieh_shortcode, `add_shortcode('pcieh', 'pcieh_shortcode');` EDIT: now that I think about it it's probably because how I call the function

Comment: putting functions in methods and using global in class is bad design, I would avoid it.  I breaks several [S.O.L.I.D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) design principals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
 public function pcieh_shortcodes_init() {
     $data = $this->data;
     var_dump($data); //Return an array which is Expected       

     function pcieh_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null) {
          global $data;
          var_dump($data); //Return NULL
      }

     add_shortcode('pcieh', 'pcieh_shortcode');
 }
```

Why not this

```
public function pcieh_shortcodes_init() {
    $data = $this->data;
    var_dump($data); //Return an array which is Expected       
    add_shortcode('pcieh', [$this,'pcieh_shortcode']);
}

public function pcieh_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null) {
    var_dump($this->data); //Return NULL
}
```

Then there is no need for `global` or any of the ugliness associated with it.  It's perfectly acceptable to pass a class and method in as an array.

Basically wordpress is using `call_user_func` to call this anyway.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

**UPDATE**

I should have noted, in the original code in the question, even if you did get it to work, you have no reference to the actual instance of this class, so any value you set in data (after assign the short code, and global) would have likely been lost anyway.  In other words you would lose the state of the current object and any data it contains.

So by using the actual instance `$this` you can be sure you are actually dealing with the instance you want to.